# Using Trigger, how to post in chatter and @mention only a selective contacts list

Tags: trigger, chatter, post

I need to post in chatter and @ mention to a selective contacts list based on specific criteria that is selected by the logged in user, when creating a specific record. (for example, corporate wants to push out a promotion using chatter to a selected list of users, based on region, type among other factors).

I believe trigger would help, but unable to figure out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a trigger on the record and then call Chatter in Apex to make the post with @mentions. Here's an [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_mention.htm) from the API documentation.

You may also want to use the [ConnectApiHelper](https://github.com/alouie-sfdc/ConnectApiHelper) class to reduce the amount of code you have to write to post the @mentions.